# Application class not loading when disabling instant run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-run

I am doing a sample project where I am using both google play services and FireBase to implement location and FCM.

I am using android studio 2.1.1 and gradle:2.1.0

So the original issue I got was :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/AppInfo;
>   at
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.(BootstrapApplication.java:126)

For this I found solution to disable instant run, so I did.
Now I was getting `DexOverflowException`, so I excluded few modules from the dependencies and all is good. But now the code in my Application class won't work. Application class `onCreate()` method does not get called.

In case anyone wondering I placed application class reference in manifest or not, I did.

```
<application
    android:name=".HHApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Here is my **project** `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Here is the **app** `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'firebase-common'
    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude module: 'play-services-basement'
        exclude module: 'play-services-task'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.26.7.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Interesting thing is, this happens only at the first time app is run. After that app works fine.

Comment: What version of gradle/gradle-wrapper are you using? Did you try `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and then `Clean` project?

Comment: Okay, I tried doing `Invalidate Caches/Restart`  and `Clean`, but it didn't work. I am using `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`

Comment: can you try with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3` and Gradle `2.14.1`?

Comment: I tried that too, it is not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

I updated the studio to 2.13 and gradle to 2.14.1 with com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3, this solved the original problem -

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/AppInfo;
>   at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.(BootstrapApplication.java:126)

Disabling instant run still doesn't worked for me.